# NumberFormatException while parsing an integer in velocity

Tags: parsing, velocity

`//$colspan` is a number in a string (eg. `$colspan="5"`). While parsing, sometimes it gives **NumberFormatException**. Any help will appreciated.

```
#set($Integer=0)       
#if($Integer.parseInt($colspan)>1)
 //some code here.....
#end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the MathTool or NumberTool from the VelocityTools project.

Comment: is there anyone ,who can give me 1 example of parsing an Integer with MathTool or NumberTool?

Comment: context.put("math", new MathTool());

Comment: #if( $math.toInteger($colspan) > 1 )